# Falha na conexão com MySQL via VBA

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando conectar a uma base de dados Mysql via VBA do Excel, mas retorna um erro informando falha catastrófica. 
Fiz um teste colocando a senha errada, ou o nome do database errado, e ele informa que o acesso foi negado ou o database não existe, então parece que está funcionando, o Mysql está respondendo, só não consegue efetivar a conexão.

Estou utilizando:

- Mysql Server 4.1
- ODBC connector 3.51

Nota: Não posso mexer na versão do Mysql Server por algumas questões. Pensei em tentar atualizar o connector para uma versão 5, mas fiquei na dúvida se não iria gerar algum outro problema com o MysqlServer.

Abaixo o codigo que estou utilizando. Tentei outras variações, mas é sempre o mesmo erro. 
Tem alguma solução para este problema?

```
 Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
 With Cn
    .ConnectionString = _
    "driver={mysql odbc 3.51 driver};" & _
    "server=localhost;database=oswau;" & _
    "uid=root;pwd=;"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
 End With
```

Adicionando mais algumas informações:
Com as informações passadas pelos colegas, atualizando o connector para versão 5 ele comunicou, porém apenas com o localhost. Quanto tento comunicar com o servidor Mysql na rede, ocorre o erro indicando:"O driver ODBC não oferece suporte para as propriedades solicitadas. Abaixo o código que estou executando para fazer a consulta. O erro ocorre quando ele tenta abrir a consulta na parte rs.open, ultima linha do código abaixo.

```
 SQLStr = "Select Count(cd_tecnico) as 'Total' from Suporte_tecnico_nacional 
 where dt_suporte between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-02' and cd_tecnico=23370"

 Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
 Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};Server=" & _
         Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
        ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

 rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
```

Comment: Existe uma [bug](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,13020,13020#msg-13020) nessa versao do *connector*. O problema ja e antigo aparentemente, por isso instalar uma nova versa do *connector* pode resolver o problema. Confirme [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-versions.html) se a sua versao do MySQL suporta a versao 5.0 do *connector*.

Comment: E se eu atualizar para uma versão 5, isso vai influenciar em mais alguma outra conexão com o MysqlServer ou apenas na conexão feita via VBA?

Comment: vai afectar todas as conexões que utilizem o conector que estejam no computador onde o VBA esta a correr.

Comment: Show de bola, atualizei o connector para versão 5.2, e agora funcionou. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente atualizar a versão do Connector. Conforme a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-versions.html) ele funciona com qualquer versão do MySQL acima da 4.1.1.

Você só precisar alterar a sua connection string:

```
 Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
 With Cn
    .ConnectionString = _
    "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};" & _
    "server=localhost;database=oswau;" & _
    "uid=root;pwd=;"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
 End With
```

Gosto de criar um DSN na minha maquina para facilitar no gerenciamento de conexões ODBC, assim caso eu atualize o conector, só preciso alterar a configuração em um lugar só.

```
Dim db As ADODB.Connection
Set db = New ADODB.Connection

conStr = "myDSN"

db.Open myDSN, "user", "pswd"
```

Vejo como criar conexões DSN no Windows [aqui](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165866/pt-br).

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso sempre deu problema de não encontrar o driver no VBA, mas na conexão vinculada ao Excel funcionava.
Alterei o nome da driver conforme a DSN de sistema do excel vinculado:

```
Sub connect2()

    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    'OMIT Dim Cn statement
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    'OMIT Dim rs statement

    Sheets("Plan1").Select
    'Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
    Server_Name = Range("b2").Value
    Database_Name = Range("b3").Value ' Name of database
    User_ID = Range("b4").Value 'id user or username
    Password = Range("b5").Value 'Password

      'DSN = "MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver Sis"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open "DSN=MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver Sis;" _
        & ";SERVER=" & Server_Name _
        & ";DATABASE=" & Database_Name _
        & ";UID=" & User_ID _
        & ";PWD=" & Password _
        & ";OPTION=3"
        '"ODBC;DSN=MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver Sis;"

        Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
            SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM `cargos` " & ";"
            rs1.Open SQLStr, conn, adOpenStatic
        With Worksheets("Planilha3").Cells(1, 1)
            .ClearContents
            .CopyFromRecordset rs1
        End With
            rs1.Close
        Set rs1 = Nothing

End Sub
```