# usar planilha do excel para preencher formulário web

Tags: microsoft-excel, formulário, vba

Tenho uma planilha no Excel, ela foi gerada a partir de um formulário de um sistema e depois alguns dados foram selecionados. Após isso tenho que colocar esses dados em um outro formulário web, esse formulário está em outro sistema diferente do que gerou a planilha inicial. Para fazer isso uso o Ctrl C + Ctrl V :( e perco muito tempo, além de ser necessário conferir os dados novamente depois.

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece algum programa específico que faz isso automaticamente, transfere os dados de uma planilha no excel para um formulário web?

Caso não conheçam, podem me dizer se é possível fazer isso usando VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jeito mais simples e barato pode ser apenas exportando para um formato CSV ou outro formato qualquer que seja fácil de importar pelo aplicativo web.

Apenas terá o trabalho de ter que criar o importador de dados na plataforma web. 
Mas ainda assim terá o trabalho manual.

Alternativamente, pode também criar uma automação mais sofisticada.

Pelo VBA, envie os dados pelo método GET ou POST.

Exemplo retirado do SO-en

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3")
```

Consulte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Desse modo, basta criar uma API para receber os dados no aplicativo web (no website). Então todo o processo continuará sendo feito dentro do Excel, sem precisar copiar e colar para um fomulário na web ou sem precisar exportar e importar para web manualmente.

Mais uma alternativa é conectar-se diretamente ao banco de dados remotamente. Para isso é preciso liberar um usuário no banco de dados para acesso remoto.

Uma vantagem é que não precisa criar nenhuma API no website pois a conexão com o banco de dados é feita de forma direta.

Esse pode ser o meio mais simples e prático para automação.

Um exemplo no SO-en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel

Um tópico aqui mesmo no SO-pt: [Falha na conexão com MySQL via VBA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43773/falha-na-conex%C3%A3o-com-mysql-via-vba)

Obviamente não vamos falar aqui sobre segurança, conceitos e demais temas relacionados pois tornaria a resposta extensa, complicada e cansativa.